# I want to crawl data from 1 to 10 pages automatically from website.How can i do it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, ipython

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
My_Url = "http://questions.consumercomplaints.in/page/2"
Data = requests.get(My_Url)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Data.content)
head_id = Soup.find_all({"div":"href"})
len(head_id)
for i in head_id:
    print i.text
```

From above code i scrapped (reviews/complaints) from web page 2.
How do i craw data automatically all pages (http://questions.consumercomplaints.in/page/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not surround your function in a ranged for loop?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range(3,11):
    My_Url = "http://questions.consumercomplaints.in/page/" + str(i)
    Data = requests.get(My_Url)
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(Data.content)
    head_id = Soup.find_all({"div":"href"})
    len(head_id)
    for i in head_id:
        print i.text
```

Have look at how the range function works [here](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/).

Comment: Am getting error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects"

Comment: Just needed to typecast i to string. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I can upvote the asnwer, Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation :(